# Xcode - header files issue with .cpp file

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I have imported my project from windows to mac and Is using xcode to compile the project.

I have managed to fix most error and bugs from the porting process but there is one bug/error I am unable to determine why its not working as it should. This probably due to my lack of knowledge of xcode but was wondering if anyone is able to help me with this problem.

The problem is this;
I have a two sub folders in my project, once called include and another called source.  Of course include contains all the header files and source contains all the cpp files and such.

Example:

```
Root/
    Include/
            Header.h
    Source/
           test.cpp
```

Now in the build settings in the xcode project, I have added $(SRCROOT)/Include/ in the Header Serach Paths.  So therefore I presume that xcode will include any header files in the Include folder.

So in the test.cpp class I add `#include "Header.h"`.  When I click build I get an error saying "'Header.h' file not found".

Im not entirely sure what I am doing wrong, of course I can do this for example - `#include "../Include/Header.h"` but that's going to be a pain going through all the cpp files in my project (which is a lot).

I was just wondering if anyone else came across this problem?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to add the headers to the `User Header Search Paths`, which if you search the help in XCode will give you the format you need to pass the directory as.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nicholas but already did try to add the header files to the User Header Search Paths and I still retrieve the same error, unless there is something else I am missing?

Comment: Hm, no that should do it. Once you've added it, have you cleaned and rebuilt?

Comment: No, I have just decided to go through each file and change how I include  files like so "../Include/Header.h".  It works so that will do.